# how to bind all events that is by human not programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind all events that is called by user i.e. click, drag, touchstart, etc.

```
function getAllEvents(element) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in element) {
        if (key.indexOf('on') === 0) {
            result.push(key);
        }
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}

var el = $('*');
el.on(getAllEvents(el), function(e) {
console.log('test'); //this is never being logged.
if (e.originalEvent !== undefined){
//coding here
}
});
```

But the `console.log('test');` is never being logged.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Can you throw this into a JSfiddle please? And, would wrapping your `el.on` in a `document.ready` help?

Comment: `element` is a *jQuery object* (in your code). I don't think it has any properties that start with `on` (besides `.on()` (ha, and `.one()` ;) )). Also, if any, you would want to add everything that comes after "on" to the string. I.e. if you find the the property "onclick", you want to add "click", not "onclick".

Comment: There's bind instead of on in the answer and I've tried that too but did nothing...And so how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you are looking for... every event on every element.. you'll get tons of logs

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h88expom/)

```
function getAllEvents(element) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in element) {
        if (key.indexOf('on') === 0) {
            result.push(key.substring(2)); //remove 'on' from key
        }
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}

$('*').each(function () { //adding for each element
    $(this).on(getAllEvents(this), function (e) { //pass element instead of jquery object
        console.log('test'); //this is being logged like crazy
        if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {
            //coding here
        }
    });
});
```

---

In the following example, I remove events with "mouse" in them (mousein, mouseout, movemove, etc) as they get a bit hectic. I use `stopPropagation()` so that each event will only get logged once (by the element it was originated in). I also added logging the type of event that gets logged so you can see what exactly is triggering each log message.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h88expom/4/)

The different lines are...

```
...
    if (key.indexOf('on') === 0 && key.indexOf('mouse') === -1) {
...
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {
        console.log('true - '+e.type);
    } else {
        console.log('false - '+e.type);
    }
...
```

Comment: Yes, it's working nice. But since I need user events only if(e.originalEvent !== undefined){console.log('user event');} and is not working...

Comment: I mean it's also on events that are be called programmatically...any idea please. Thank you.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. Here ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h88expom/1/)) I created a click event that runs after 3 seconds (don't touch the result pane for atleast that long)... you'll see a different result in the logs than when you manually do stuff. For the call on `click()`, your originalEvent condition is `false` (its repeated because it continues to bubble up). When you interact with elements manually, you should see `true` being logged.

Comment: Oh! it's on mousemove too, so I confused.

Comment: You wanted every event, mousemove is one of them. And these events bubble too... so you're getting tons of events and many of them will get logged many times depending on how deep your html is... if you want to prevent some, you could exclude from the list... also you could stopPropagation if you don't want them to bubble up.

Comment: Can I just exclude mousemove and similar for touch devices?

Comment: @C-linkNepal, here is an example using `stopPropagation()` and removing all events with "mouse" in them... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h88expom/2/). You can customize which events you remove if you like.

Comment: stopPropagation just prevents the event from bubbling... so like if you have `<div><button>foo</button></div>`... `div` wouldn't get an event that originated in `button`. I removed mouse related events by adding to the conditional for pushing to result. [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/h88expom/3/) is another example if you are interested in seeing what events are getting triggered (other than mousein/out/move/etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as per [jQuery's blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) by using jQuery's internal method `$._data(element, "events");`

```
function getAllEvents(element) {
    return Object.keys($._data(element, "events")).join(" ");
}
```

Comment: I got : TypeError: $._data(...) is not an object

Comment: have you included jQuery?

Comment: @C-linkNepal a jsfiddle?